# How to add zoom to this code? On touch works great and moves image

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, scale

Is there anyway to use matrix or scale gesture to this code ? I can move image arround x,y but cant zoom in or out. Any advice would be welcome :)

this is my class

```
class SimpleFloatingWindow constructor(private val context: Context) {


    private var windowManager: WindowManager? = null
        get() {
            if (field == null) field = (context.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager)
            return field
        }

    private var floatView: View =
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_floating_window, null)

    private lateinit var layoutParams: WindowManager.LayoutParams

    private var lastX: Int = 0
    private var lastY: Int = 0
    private var firstX: Int = 0
    private var firstY: Int = 0

    private var isShowing = false
    private var touchConsumedByMove = false






    private val onTouchListener = View.OnTouchListener { view, event ->
        val totalDeltaX = lastX - firstX
        val totalDeltaY = lastY - firstY

        when (event.actionMasked) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                lastX = event.rawX.toInt()
                lastY = event.rawY.toInt()
                firstX = lastX
                firstY = lastY
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                view.performClick()
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                val deltaX = event.rawX.toInt() - lastX
                val deltaY = event.rawY.toInt() - lastY
                lastX = event.rawX.toInt()
                lastY = event.rawY.toInt()
                if (abs(totalDeltaX) >= 5 || abs(totalDeltaY) >= 5) {
                    if (event.pointerCount == 1) {
                        layoutParams.x += deltaX
                        layoutParams.y += deltaY
                        touchConsumedByMove = true
                        windowManager?.apply {
                            updateViewLayout(floatView, layoutParams)
                        }
                    } else {
                        touchConsumedByMove = false
                    }
                } else {
                    touchConsumedByMove = false
                }
            }
            else -> {
            }
        }
        touchConsumedByMove
    }

    init {
        with(floatView) {
            closeImageButton.setOnClickListener { dismiss() }

        }

        floatView.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener)

        layoutParams = WindowManager.LayoutParams().apply {
            format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
            flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            type = when {
                Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O ->
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
                else -> WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST
            }

            gravity = Gravity.CENTER
            width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just been reading about moving and scaling floating windows and found this article           "Resizing the window is very similar to moving it, and you can use the same DraggableTouchListener as we introduced in the Moving Window article. Just change x and y for width and height."

Comment: Is that possible just by changing x and you with width and height ?